# Json Regex string tel number exporting

Tags: json, web-crawler

Hello I am trying to write a code which will export telephone numbers from a website when a URL is given which I what I have achieved. However this code displays all numbers within the website, **how can I amend this code to retrieve only UK telephone numbers?**. Any help, suggestions or criticism is appreciated. Inspired by this http://www.convertcsv.com/phone-extractor.htm
Code displayed below, Thanks.

```
    <script>
  function assignText(s) {
       document.getElementById('txt1').value = s;
    }
    function runit(s) {
    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('5 t,j,k,v;5 B=3.6("V").l;5 z=3.6("W").l;5 a=[];5 m=3.6("T").l;5 E=3.6("R").l;5 h="Y";5 e=4;7(3.6("x")){e=3.6("x").9;7(11(e))e=4;J e*=1}5 r={};r.C=L 10("\\\\+?\\\\(?\\\\d*\\\\)? ?\\\\(?\\\\d+\\\\)?\\\\d*([\\\\s./-]\\\\d{2,})+","g");5 c=3.6("G").9*1||1;7(c<1)c=1;5 8=P(3.N[0].K);7(8=="o")8=3.6("M").9;7(!8)8=",";5 A=r.C;5 a=s.O(A)||[];a=p.I(a,D(f){F f.w()});a=p.H(a,D(f){F f.X().w().q>=e&&!(/\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d/.Z(f))});7(z)a=a.12();7(B)a=p.13(a,Q);3.6(\'i\').9="";5 b=[];7(m&&c>1){b.y(h+"1");u(j=2;j<=c;j++){b.y(h+j)}h=b.S(8)}7(m){3.6(\'i\').9+=h+"\\n"}u(j=0;j<a.q;){u(k=0;k<c;k++,j++){7(j<a.q){v=a[j].w();7(E)v=v.U(8);3.6(\'i\').9+=v}7(k<c-1){3.6(\'i\').9+=8}}3.6(\'i\').9+="\\n"}',62,66,'|||document||var|getElementById|if|delimiter|value|||cols||minLen|||heading|txta|||checked|hdr|||_|length|res|||for||trim|txtMinLen|push|sorted|re|dup|phone|function|forceCsv|return|txtNumCols|filter|map|else|outsep|new|outSepOtherVal|forms|match|radiovalue|true|chkForceCsv|join|chkCsvHeader|toCsv|chkDup|chkSort|removePunctuation|Phone|test|RegExp|isNaN|sort|uniq'.split('|'),0,{}))

    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use google's libphonenumber, it has a javascript implementation:

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

The library has a function called parse

```
parse(text, options)
```

The text parameter would be your phone number, in the options parameter, you could put a [country code](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js#country-code-definition). When the library is able to parse the number as a UK phone number, you know the number is valid.